# how to render multiple js.erb files in same method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
   def react
 @postsAlPHA = @user.find(params[:liked_post]).page(params[:page])
    @postsBETA = @user.find(params[:disliked_post]).page(params[:page])
end
```

so I am trying to make @postsAlPHA to render alpha.js.erb for pagination
and `@postsBETA` to render

```
BETA.js.erb  
<% @postsAlPHA.each do |x| %>
<% x.body %>
<% end %>
<%= paginate @postsAlPHA %>
<% @postsBETA.each do |u| %>
<% x.content %>
<% end %>
<%= paginate @postsBETA %>
```

Comment: Capitalization matters in Ruby. You write `@postsALPhA`, `@postsALPha`, and `@postsALPHA`, but those are not the same variable. The standard way of writing that instance variable would be `@posts_alpha`, lowercase with underscores.

Comment: SORRY FOR THE TYPO ... UPDATED THE QUESTION @Rory O'Kane

Answer (score 0):

Turn them into partials, then render them in your view. Make sure to prefix the filenames with `_` e.g. `_alpha.js.erb`.

In your view:

```
<%= render partial: 'path/to/alpha.js.erb' %>
<%= render partial: 'path/to/beta.js.erb' %>
```

Comment: no I am doing this for the remote true as when i click a link it renders specific js.erb for certain action...